# Unexpected Javascript onkeydown event and document.write

Tags: javascript, onkeydown, document.write

I am learning Javascript and when I am testing some features, I found some problems. Here are my codes:

```
    <script>
        function onCreate() {
            var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; 
            body.focus(); 
            body.onkeydown = function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 32) {
                    alert(1); 
                    sayHey(); 
                }
            }
        }

        function sayHey() {
            document.write("Hey "); 
            document.write("May"); 
        }, 30); 
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="onCreate()">
</body>
```

As you may try, onkeydown event works perfectly when I do not include sayHello() function, which make use of setInterval.
When sayHello() is included, when I click space bar, "Hey May" is created which is as expected. However, when I click space bar once more, no alert message and no new "Hey May" is raised. It seems that onkeydown() function do NOT work anymore. Why is it the case?

In addition, when I change `document.write(brabrabra)` to the below one, it works.

```
var newParagraph = document.createElement('p'); 
var text = "Hey May"; 
var textNode = document.createTextNode(text); 
newParagraph.appendChild(textNode); 
body.appendChild(newParagraph);
```

Why is it the case? Can someone explain to me please? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the document has been parsed, the current document is closed and any use of `document.write()` will clear the current document and open a new blank document, thus clearing any event handlers or content you previously had.

So, in your specific example, the first key press triggers your event handler.  That shows the `alert(1)` and then calls `sayHey()` which calls `document.write()` which clears the current document and thus your event handler is no longer there.  So, for the second press of the space bar there is no event handler in place and nothing happens.

So, if you want to add content to the document after it has been loaded, then you should add the content with something like `document.createElement()` and `.appendChild()`, not `document.write()`.

Comment: Just one question in mind... if `document.write()` clear the current document and open a new blank document. why do consecutive `document.write()` works... why not document.write("May") overwrite document.write("Hey ") ?

Comment: @CHANist - Because once you've opened a new document, it remains open so you can write to it more.  It is the fact that the document is closed when it is originally done parsing that causes your issue.

Comment: Can I say when I create events that link with human interaction, since the computer do not know when to stop parsing, it will parse when onkeydown() finish once. But not in the case, like setInterval, since computer know that she needs to run the code every says 200 microsecond.
Is what I said here, right, or still misunderstanding the issue? Many thanks.

Comment: @CHANist - That does not sound right to me, but honestly I don't really understand what you're trying to say.  It's really very simple.  When the browser loads a web page, it then parses the page from start to end of the original HTML.  While the page is being parsed (before the parser gets to the end of the page), the document is "open" and `document.write()` will go into that document.  When the parser gets to the end of the HTML of the page, the document is then closed.  Code that runs in response to user events like a click, runs after the document has been closed.